# iOS IAP item rename issue

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I want to rename IAP item which was registered on iTunes.
I needed to upgrade my game so I changed display name of IAP item.
But When I purchase, the purchasing pop up text is not changed.
I changed its name correctly on iTunes.
But I can see the string, "Pending", orange letters.
I don`t know that this is and why pop up text is not changed right now.
I noticed before that after I changed some items on iTunes, it reflected on my app soon.
But in this occasion, nothing happened.
Please tell me why.

Answer (score 1):

I believe apple reviews the In App Purchases changes before they go into effect in order to prevent tricking users into buying something they did not originally want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So does it mean the IAP display name will be able to be changed after app is republished?

Comment: @NewBeginner I believe the iAP display name will be reviewed individually and it will change when it passes the review. No new build needed.